# Performing Distance Calculation using Excel?

Tags: distance, excel

Is there a way (preferably in Excel) to calculate the distance (based on lat, lon) between two lists of points?

My end goal would be, for example, to have a list of Starbucks and a list of McDonald's, and then show the nearest neighbor, if you will.

Comment: I'm looking for minimum distance.

Comment: By which unet, will return the distance?

Comment: @Jeed Any unit would be fine, probably miles in this case.

Answer (score 17):

Given a list of geographic coordinate pairs, you can implement the [**Haversine formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) directly in Excel.

---

The simplest way to use this (or a more accurate, but I think it's not your case) formula consists into press `Alt+F11` to open the VBA Editor, click `Insert --> Module` and then (copy and) paste e.g. the [code](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#Excel) kindly suggested by blah238.

```
Public Function getDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)  
earth_radius = 6371  
Pi = 3.14159265  
deg2rad = Pi / 180  

dLat = deg2rad * (latitude2 - latitude1)  
dLon = deg2rad * (longitude2 - longitude1)  

a = Sin(dLat / 2) * Sin(dLat / 2) + Cos(deg2rad * latitude1) * Cos(deg2rad * latitude2) * Sin(dLon / 2) * Sin(dLon / 2)  
c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(a))  

d = earth_radius * c  

getDistance = d  

End Function
```

There will be a new custom `getDistance` function (unit = kilometer) available in your spreadsheet which accepts four parameters, i.e. the two pairs of coordinates, as follow:

```
getDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)
```

where `latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2` should be replaced by their relative cell references.

[image]

Comment: Direct link: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#Excel

Comment: @blah238 Thanks for your suggestion. I've added a short how-to in order to make it working.

Comment: @afalciano Thanks for the walk through & code.  My question though is what are the ultimate units from this equation? is it meters?

Comment: @Kerry It's kilometers. Also, where the formula says "Sqr" it should be "Sqrt".

Comment: The unit of measure of distances is kilometers, just like the Earth radius.

Answer (score 3):

A more accurate way is to use [Vicenty's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) formula. It is based on an ellipsoid instead of a sphere. However, the previous answer will do the job if you work in a city (differences can be neglected in your case). I've found an excel vb code [here](http://www.contextures.com/excellatitudelongitude.html#code) just in case.

Note that if you work in a city, using "bird flight" distances could be misleading. It would be better to use network distances. A compromise is to use "Manhattan distance"