# Distance calculation using ST_Distance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, algorithm, st-distance, implementation

I am trying to calculate the distance using the ST_Distance function in the postgres database.

I am using following query:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(52.3551151038034 4.87660185549649)')
  , ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(52.3549985339677 4.87622001617791)')
);
```

For this the distance is returned as 44.159975697 meters.

When I am comparing this value with other sources, for example [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) explained in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88484/excel-distance-calculation).
The Haversine formula return the value as 0.0289913126501404, which is roughly 29 meters.

What am I doing wrong with my query here?

Comment: Just in case, did you checked that you didn't swap latitude and longitude when entering your coordinates ? `ST_GeogFromText` use WKT geometry so coordinates have to be POINT(longitude, latitude)

Comment: I would think if he swapped lat and long his calculated difference would be greater than 29 meters..

Comment: mgc was right.  He flipped the coords. I posted an answer

Comment: @mgc, yes you are correct. I had by mistake swapped the lat-log values. Switching them back gives the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You swapped the long, lat.  Common mistake.

If you do this:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(4.87660185549649 52.3551151038034 )')
, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(4.87622001617791 52.3549985339677 )')
);
```

Answer is:

29.07032499 meters

You can even get closer to Havershine, by forcing the distance formula to use sphere instead of spheroid by passing in false for the optional use_spheroid arg (it defaults to true).

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(4.87660185549649 52.3551151038034 )')
, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(4.87622001617791 52.3549985339677   )'), false);
```

Yields:

28.99135257

Which is pretty close to your Havershine answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Haversine formula assumes the earth is a perfect sphere whereas SRID 4326 is a better, more oddly shaped representation.

<strike>ST_Distance on SRID 4326 does not result in meters but rather degrees.</strike>

You'll need to choose a map projection with its measurement defined in meters (or feet) or cast into a geography.

here is another useful link:  [Why is result of ST_Area or ST_Distance in SRID 4326 so small](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124027/why-is-result-of-st-area-or-st-distance-in-srid-4326-so-small)

Comment: the points are in geography.. `ST_Distance( geog, geog )` is not `ST_Distance( geom, geom )`

Comment: In fact, the accept answer tells him to use Geography, which is exactly what Ashish is already doing with `ST_GeogFromText`

Comment: You are right, I glossed right over that!

Comment: @EvanCarroll that was some good research/information in the answer you deleted

Comment: I could bring it back in a different question if you thought it was helpful, but it didn't address the problem here.

Comment: I brought it back here, http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/217519/6052