# Investigating PostGIS functions to see what they are doing?

Tags: postgis, algorithm, debugging, st-distance

Let's say you have a function like [`ST_Distance`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) and I want to know how it works. The docs don't say much at all, how do I go about debugging this or figuring out how it ticks.

Comment: Your question links to the old version 2.0 docs. See the current documentation [`ST_Distance`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) which have been expanded.

Comment: @MikeT updated with the new link, though I don't think it changes anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful, let's go down the rabbit hole. First we need to know what's happening when you call the function in SQL. To do this we reference the output of `\dS+`. `\dS+` shows the override table with one entry for every function and prototype, as well as the function that it is dispatching to.

1. You're calling `ST_Distance($1::geog,$2::geog)`.
2. `ST_Distance($1::geog,$2::geog)` is calling `_st_distance($1::geog, $2::geog, 0.0, true)`
3. `_st_distance($1::geog, $2::geog, 0.0, true)` is calling a C function called `geography_distance`

From there we need to start looking into the C functions,

4. `geography_distance` is a self-named function on [:201 in `postgis/postgis/geography_measurement.c`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/postgis/geography_measurement.c#L201)
5. `geography_distance` then calls `lwgeom_distance_spheroid(lwgeom1, lwgeom2, &s, tolerance);`
6. `lwgeom_distance_spheroid` is defined in the liblwgeom used by PostGIS on [:2091 of lwgeodetic.c](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/cc3437595e88eac7f20b0f3b780a3816cdc912c9/liblwgeom/lwgeodetic.c#L2091).
7. Because you're giving it two points, that calls [`ptarray_distance_spheroid` which is defined here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/cc3437595e88eac7f20b0f3b780a3816cdc912c9/liblwgeom/lwgeodetic.c#L1741)
8. `pt_array_distance_spheroid` internally calls [liblwgeom's `spheroid_distance`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/liblwgeom/lwspheroid.c#L79) and finally..

**we have code**

```
/**
* Computes the shortest distance along the surface of the spheroid
* between two points, using the inverse geodesic problem from
* GeographicLib (Karney 2013).
*
* @param a - location of first point
* @param b - location of second point
* @param s - spheroid to calculate on
* @return spheroidal distance between a and b in spheroid units
*/
double spheroid_distance(const GEOGRAPHIC_POINT *a, const GEOGRAPHIC_POINT *b, const SPHEROID *spheroid)
{
    struct geod_geodesic gd;
    geod_init(&gd, spheroid->a, spheroid->f);
    double lat1 = a->lat * 180.0 / M_PI;
    double lon1 = a->lon * 180.0 / M_PI;
    double lat2 = b->lat * 180.0 / M_PI;
    double lon2 = b->lon * 180.0 / M_PI;
    double s12; /* return distance */
    geod_inverse(&gd, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, &s12, 0, 0);
    return s12;
}
```

So that's what eventually get's called and does the lifting when you call `ST_Distance`. The beef of that is `geod_inverse`. Not seeing that in `lwspheroid.c`, I googled and it seems to come from [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/C/geodesic_8h.html). Looking back at `lwspheroid.c` you can see that being included here,

```
/* GeographicLib */
#if PROJ_GEODESIC
#include <geodesic.h>
#endif
```

And GeographicLib provides *an implementation in C of the geodesic algorithms described in C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for geodesics, J. Geodesy 87, 43–55 (2013); DOI: 10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z* you can see [`geod_inverse` documented here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/C/geodesic_8h.html#a19bc3d000428010ad9d8509174e672c9). You can find the [implementation here on line :1054](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/C/geodesic_8c_source.html)

This also matches a patch accepted only 17 months ago, [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2918) to move to use to GeographicLib.

So that's what it looks like to debug PostGIS and Postgres from the top to the bottom.

Comment: Very helpful and informative!

Answer (score 1):

You can also download and debug the source code from Git repository. I personally looked up the function definitions by debugging the source code in Visual Studio and viewing the collaboration diagrams available at http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/annotated.html